# how to setting fixed position of canvas using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem i have create multiple texts and a canvas file for the snake game in javascript however when i load it all in the browser (using Firefox) the resolution on my screen changes the snake-game and so i created this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js" class="snake">
    var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    </script>
```

can i move this script using css and tagging the class to make the script run on the left side of my browser if so how do i define the class in css?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="textrotate.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <p class="warning">Warning do not press multiple keys simultaneous if you do you will lose and have to start from the beginning.</p>

    <p class="warning2">The right side and the bottom u can go through however you might lose your snake (possible to turn back) and the<br>left and the upper side touch them and its game over.</p>

    <p class="enjoy">Good luck and enjoy the game!!!</p>

    <pre class="normal">
    snake
    </pre>
    <div>
    <pre class="rotate">
    snake
    </pre>

    <pre class="rotate2">
    snake
    </pre>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="450" style="border:1px solid #CCFF00;">
    </canvas>


    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <audio id="audio_1" hidden="true" autoplay="autoplay" controls preload>
<source src="sound.wav">
<source src="sound.mp3">
<source src="sound.ogg">
    </audio>
    <audio id="audio_2" controls preload hidden="true" >
<source src="sound.wav">
<source src="sound.mp3">
<source src="sound.ogg">
    </audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('audio_1').addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.pause();
    document.getElementById('audio_2').play();
}, false);

document.getElementById('audio_2').addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.pause();
    document.getElementById('audio_1').play();
}, false);

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js" class="snake">
    var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');



    </script> 
    </body>

    </html>
```

the css:

```
    pre.rotate2{
transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);    
display:block;
font-size:82%;
color:yellow;
position:fixed;
bottom:300px;
right:-110px;
}

    pre.rotate{
transform:rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);   
display:block;
font-size:82%;
color:lime;
position:fixed;
bottom:290px;
right:5px;
}

    pre.normal{
float:left;
color:cyan;
}

    body{
background-color: black;
}

    p.warning{
color: #FF66CC;
position:fixed;
font-size: 90%;
bottom:16%;
left:0.3%;
}

    p.warning2{
color: #FF66CC;
position:fixed;
font-size: 90%;
bottom:12%;
left:0.3%;
}

    p.enjoy{
color: #FF66CC;
position:fixed;
bottom:10%;
left:0.3%;
}
```

Comment: Scripts don't run on a particular side of your browser; they're not visible at all. It's the `<canvas>` element that you need to position.

Comment: ooh i see at the moment i have this:
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="450" style="border:1px solid #CCFF00;">
</canvas>
how can i make it fixed on one spot?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by, "fixed in one spot", and what the rest of the page looks like.

Comment: May be you need position: static;

Comment: ok ill send an update on my real question with full code on css and html

Comment: You should write a descriptive title that summarizes the question you are asking. As of now, this is really “not a real question”.

Comment: im using pre because i have three ascii snake names however they were too troublesome to fix so i replaced them with snake

Comment: so i've been thinking and was wondering that since i give the canvas the id="canvas" wouldn't it be possible in css to just write something like this:
#canvas{
bottom:10%;
etc.
}